# Why can't I render these videos without audio being out of sync?

Tags: audio, sync

I've pulled out all guns to merge 13 episodes into one video, failing and staring at a brick wall. I've rendered on KDenlive in Linux and Davinci Resolve on Windows.

I even screen recorded the whole damn thing in OBS, still audio out of sync and midway it just starts choking, stuttering and leaving gaps without audio XD

When I play the original videos in VLC, they play just fine. My problem is simply that I don't know what is causing issues here.

Here's the mediainfo output of all the episodes, hoping somebody more savvy can see the culprit in it.

https://pastebin.com/3mQ4Q1wV

Answer (score 1):

The issue was, the videos had a `variable frame rate` which choked up the editors.

The solution was using `Handbrake` to encode the videos with a `constant frame rate`.